# HI mysql update

Tags: mysql, mysqlupgrade

HI I want to change the first name to grouocho if name is harpo and last name is Williamns other vise I want to change to Mocho Groucho where first name is Harpo. When I run my code it gives me

```
Error   1175    You are using safe update mode and you tried to 
update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column
```

Could Anyone help me?

```
UPDATE actor
SET first_name = 
CASE 
    WHEN first_name = 'HARPO' AND last_name = 'Williams' THEN 'GROUCHO'
    WHEN first_name = 'HARPO' AND last_name != 'Williams' THEN 'MOCHO GROUCHO'
END
;
```

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message? Or searching here on SO? If you do, you will find many results that explain the error message and how to fix it.

Comment: Yes I did , they mostly talk about  SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0 but I didn't understand how rely this work I  am student started the learn MySQL I dint wanna break my settings because I need my program at school.I was expecting this code should work

Comment: Well, you found the answer, you just need to use it. You can always change the setting back.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project! Come back anytime when you get stuck.